# Branch IO UNity getting first install

Tags: unity-game-engine, branch.io

I Have integrated branch plugin in my Unity game.
How to get to know if current install was done by branch link and is it new install??
How to get to know if any user has installed from another user invite and reward the referrer.
what is "+is_first_session" used for??

Answer (score 0):

**1. How to get to know if current install was done by branch link and is it new install??**

If you integrate the Branch SDK in your app such that Branch is initialized everytime you app is opened/installed, the Branch SDK will return
EITHER

- the following parameters (in case of an organic install/open)

`+clicked_branch_link:false`

`+is_first_session:true/false`

OR

- Link parameters (if a Branch link was clicked which led to an install/open) along with the following parameters:

`+clicked_branch_link:true`

`+is_first_session:true/false`

The `is_first_session` parameter is set to `true` in case of a fresh install for the device. (PS: Branch is able to detect a reinstall as well, so if a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, is_first_session parameter is set to `false`)

The `+clicked_branch_link` parameter is set to `true` is the install/open occured due to a Branch link click.

**2. How to get to know if any user has installed from another user invite and reward the referrer.**

Branch has an inbuilt system in place to setup a referral program. The referral system with Branch allows you to reward users with credits (for any event e.g. referring other users), track those credits, and redeem them when appropriate. 
You can refer to the documentation for the setup [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/referrals/#overview). There is also an informative blog available [here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-build-an-optimized-referral-program-for-your-mobile-app/).

Comment: My Problem is i have my app released already and i am giving the referral rewards in next update, so is there a way to check if previous users try to get reward? i don't want to reward previous users. only give rewards to new users??

Comment: whether the new install is credited to the specified bucket, so that it can be checked anytime later by Branch.loadRewards method?

Comment: @PrathviShetty You can define the referral rule on the branch dashboard for a custom event. If the user who clicks on a referral link and installs the app is a first time user you will get `+is_first_session` parameter as `true` in your app. If the user already has the app or reinstalls the app, the `+is_first_session` parameter will be set to `false`. You can use this parameter and only if it is a first time user, you can fire the custom event you have defined. Branch is will then automatically assign the referral rewards to the appropriate bucket.

Comment: You can find the documentation on custom events [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/unity/#track-custom-events)

Comment: Another problem that im facing now is the integration for android inUnity as im using another plugin which also needs to override manifest

Comment: You should replace

<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity">

with

<activity android:name="io.branch.unity.BranchUnityActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">  Here how to handle if i have another plugin that also needs to override the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the true string on iOS and android ,
In IOS it comes as "True" while in android we get "true"